# How to list content of a directory (vsftpd)?

Tags: vsftpd

This question could be a follow-up of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/591952/ftp-hanging-at-150-here-comes-the-directory-listing) question. Where the OP was asking
about how to list directory contents using passive mode and specific ports.

I wonder how do I do it in **active mode using default port 21** ?

This is how I've been doing it until now:

[image: input screenshot]

"Here comes the directory listing." and that's where it all ends.

Am I missing something here ?

Output from log:

[image]

Comment: The contents of the directory isn't being listed in the output. I used `put` to upload 2 text files so 2 text files should've been listed.

Comment: What's in the log on the server?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Do you know where it's usually located ? On the web I found `ftp.log` but `whereis ftp.log` gave me nothing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I found it and added it to my question. It's clear that I made 2 successful uploads. So empty directory can be ruled out.

Comment: I noticed `dir` works locally in ftp shell for listing files but it doesn't work when I connect to the ftp server remotely.

Comment: You tried it in passive mode?

Comment: No. I keep trying making it work with out-of-the-box configuration.

Comment: The thing is the ftp server is in Virtualbox and I'm connecting to it from host machine. That probably is playing its role in this as well.

Comment: Nobody does active mode FTP anymore. Not for decades. Mostly nobody does FTP at all anymore.

Comment: I know it's an obsolete tech. I'm doing this just for experimental / education purposes.

Comment: Nobody bothers with ftp server anymore. You can host your own cloud storage or simply use third-party solutions.